# Prove or disprove: if $\sum\limits_{n=0}^∞a_n$ converges and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n =0$, then $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n b_n$ converges.

Tags: calculus

Prove or disprove: if $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n$  converges and $\lim\limits_{n→\infty}⁡b_n =0$, then $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n  b_n$ converges.

I tried this example $$a_n= b_n = \frac {(-1)^n} {\sqrt {n+1}},$$ this will show that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n  b_n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {1} { {n+1}},$$ which is the Harmonic series, diverges.

However, I tried every convergent test but I couldn't show that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^n} {\sqrt {n+1}}$$ converges.

Comment: Hint: for the last question, use the [alternating series convergence test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Comment: It converges by Leibniz' test.

Comment: I haven't learn any of these test yet

Comment: But you still can read the Wikipedia article, though? (or do you mean you are not *allowed* to use anything not seen in class?)

Comment: I'm not allowed to do so :D

Comment: OK - which tests did you see so far?

Comment: I can use comparison, integral (which I'd avoid if I can), and ratio test.

Comment: mmh... with this only, not sure to see how to do. All the examples will involve $a_n$ being alternating (if it isn't, say it is non-negative, then $|a_n b_n| = o(a_n)$ and the comparison test ensures $\sum a_n b_n$ will converge) -- so you'll have to find an alternating series, non absolutely convergent, for which you can still prove convergence with these limited tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convergence of 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+1}}.
$$
Let $s_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k+1}}$. Then $s_{2n-1}$, $n\in\mathbb N$, is increasing, while  $s_{2n}$, $n\in\mathbb N$, is decreasing and
$$
s_1\le s_3\le\cdots\le s_{2n-1}\le s_{2n+1}\le s_{2n}\le s_{2n-2}\le\cdots s_2\le s_0.
$$
Hence both these subsequence are convergent, as monotonic and bounded, and their limits coincide, as 
$$
s_{2n}-s_{2n-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\longrightarrow 0.
$$ 
Thus $\{s_n\}$ converges.

This is the alternating series test: If $a_n>0$, $a_n$ decreasing and $a_n\to 0$, then
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

Take $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}$ for $n\geqslant 0$, and let $b_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln(n+1)}$ for $n\geqslant 1$. The series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ converges to $\ln{2}$ 
while the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\cdot b_n$ diverges since
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} a_n\cdot b_n=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}\sim \ln\ln{N},\quad N\to\infty.$$

Comment: I need to do this at the initial point $n=0$

Comment: Choosing $b_0=1$, instead of $b_0=0$, could change the sum of a convergent series but has no effect on a divergent series.